# Worklight: Timeout does not log out users

Tags: timeout, ibm-mobilefirst

I have specified below settings in my App but App is not getting Time out?

```
timeout: 60000 ,
heartBeatIntervalInSecs: 5 * 60
```

I have modified my code and am trying to re-load the App when connection goes down. It asks the user to re-load or close the App. But both functions are not working correctly. The event gets fired correctly but the specified library functions are not working as expected here. The close function is only taking App in the background and killing the App process.

```
onConnectionFailure: function (){ 
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("Communication Failure", "An unexpected server connection error has occurred. Please try again later.", 
    [{text : 'Reload',  handler : function () {   WL.Client.init(wlInitOptions); }} ,       {text : 'Close',handler : function () {  WL.App.close(); }  } ,     ]);     }
```

Anything else that i have to set?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the init options obj if you want Timeout:

```
{ 
 Timeout: 60000,
 heartBeatIntervalInSecs: 5 * 60,
 connectOnStartup : true,
 onConnectionFailure : function () { 
      alert('failed');
   }
}
```

If after `60000`ms there is not connection to the Worklight Server, you should get the `failed` alert.

The documentation is [here](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_init.html). Also note the the Timeout applies to more than just that init call. See the following:

> An integer value, denoting the timeout in milliseconds. The timeout
>   affects all calls from the app to the IBM® Worklight® Server. If not
>   specified, a timeout of 30,000 milliseconds (30 seconds) is used.

This however, will **not** logout users. I assume you need to set some session expiration data on your server to logout users after a certain time. You may want look at [WL.Client.logout](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_logout.html).

Comment: i have onFailure function defined in the "initOptions.js" file and it is not getting fired once Server connection has been established one time. Is there any difference between onFailure and onConnectionFailure  inside "initOptions.js" file? thanks

Comment: "If an onFailure function is not passed, a default onFailure function is called. If onFailure is passed, it overrides any specific failure-handling function." onConnectionFailure is a specific error handeling function: "A failure handling function invoked when connection to the IBM Worklight Server, performed on initialization by default, or if the connectOnStartup flag is true, fails." [Link to Docs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m6/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_init.html)